# WPF: TemplateSelectors for different GridViews

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, datatemplateselector

Currently I have a UserControl that displays collections of data in the same layout. So one control could be instanced with a collection of ObjectA and another of ObjectB. I then use TemplateSelectors to choose the right DataTemplates.

Later on we thought we'd set the List as a GridView to show more information in the list itself. However each type of object has different properties and the columns may have different names and not the same quantity. I realized then that the columns and such where not set in the ItemTemplate but at the GridView itself and ListView of course has no templateSelector for itself.

I wasn't sure how to do it but several ways came into mind.

1) There is some kind of TemplateSelector property I'm not aware off.

2) I CAN set it somehow at the ItemTemplateSelector only don't know how.

3) I could do the GridView dynamically (could be difficult and wan't to avoid).

Any good way to do this, tutorials or similiar I could use?

EDIT:

As I have learned a little bit more about ListView and it's view property I'm pretty sure I could define the gridview in a staticResource. Still I would love a ViewSelector or something similar. I guess this was of course not intended as the the item could be dynamic while the Collection isn't.

But I'm thinking about cases where there could exist more types of view then gridview ( iconview or something else) and the user could switch between them it would have to be implemented in some way.

The solution I see know is using a trigger and basing it on the first item in the collection but I'm not liking that too much.

Comment: Did you ever find any information on this? I have the same requirements.

Comment: @Rob I ended up doing something completely different if I recall correctly. There is a new answer here you might wan't to check out. Please let me know if that works so I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the AutoGeneratingColumns property of the Grid?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.95).aspx